# mysql trigger to update parent record on updated

Tags: mysql, triggers, parent-child

I have two tables one called `note_category` and the other called `fs_note`.
`note_category` table structure is:

```
ID | CTG_ENG_TITL | CTG_PARENT_ID
```

`fs_note` table structure is:

```
ID | NOTE_CAT | CRNT_YEAR_VAL| PRV_YEAR_VAL
```

I want to create triggers on the `fs_note` table to make the following:

1. After add: add the `CRNT_YEAR_VAL` and the `PRV_YEAR_VAL` of the last inserted record to its parent note according to the category table hierarchy.
2. Before delete: Subtract the `CRNT_YEAR_VAL` and the `PRV_YEAR_VAL` of the record to be deleted from its parent note according to the category table hierarchy.
3. Before update: do the same as number 2.
4. After update: do the same as number 1.

The thing is I want it to be recursive as I have unlimited category depth, so for example if I have:

```
Note1:
    Note1.1:
        Note1.1.1
        Note1.1.2
    Note1.2:
        Note1.2.1
```

I want the value of `Note1.2.1` to be added to the value of `Note1.2` and the values of `Note1.1.1`, `Note1.1.2` to be added to the value of `Note1.1`. Then the values of `Note1.1` and `Note1.2` to be added to the value of `Note1` and so on.

Any ideas how to do that?

Comment: So now I have two tables one called fs_note the other called dumy_fs_note
I created after Insert and after Delete triggers on the fs_table that insert a row with calculated data to the dumy_fs_table that has an after update trigger that should update a certain row in fs_table with the new values
The problem is that now i am having error `#1442 Can't update table 'fs_note' in stored function/trigger because it is already used by statement which invoked this stored function/trigger.` why is that?? it is the dumy_fs_note table that is trying to update the fs_table
Any idea what's wrong?
Thanks

Comment: I don't think you can, won't the trigger not be able to get a lock on the parent table because it is already being edited?